# How does Telegram sends Images and Videos in Android App?

Tags: java, android, image, android-image, telegram

I am working on a messaging chat app. I have gone through the code of Telegram Android App but did not get how do they send images and videos in the chat. It would be really helpful if you can explain the method or give any reference for the same.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send any kind of file using MultiPart content from an android app. You need  to include the 2 libraries in your build.gradle

```
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.3'


  private void sendImage(final String fileString, String fileMessageId)

{
    Bitmap bitmap;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;


    String sResponse = null;
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileString);

    File sourceFile = new File(fileString);


    String upLoadServerUri = WSConfig.UPLOAD_FILE_URL;
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(upLoadServerUri);


    try {


        MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        entity.addPart("files",
                new FileBody(sourceFile));


        httpPost.setEntity(entity);
        HttpResponse response;
        try {
            response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                            response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
            sResponse = reader.readLine();




        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to send the image as bytes itself not upload it to any server.

Comment: You can send it through Base64 string

Comment: I will try it. Thanks :)